# Does multiple ARRAY_AGG retain the same order for all of them?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been an adept of using nested & repeated fields (i.e., arrays and structs) to model data efficiently and help my end-user understand relations between data without them needing to go on a "JOIN wild hunt".

Whenever I need to model more than one field inside an entity, as best practice, I have been using AoS (array of multiple structs) like `ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(...))` or `ARRAY_AGG(SELECT AS STRUCT ...)` and using that I retain the original position order for each value inside a struct.

Out of curiosity, what about the order in SoA - structs of multiple arrays, or simply multiple ARRAY_AGG?

For example, lets imagine a key-value pair (no `NULLs`) modeled by using `SELECT x, ARRAY_AGG(key) AS key, ARRAY_AGG(value) as value FROM ...`. Google says ([Working with arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays)) that for a single array *"The array returned by ARRAY_AGG() is in an arbitrary order, since the order in which the function concatenates values is not guaranteed"*. However, every test I made for multiple `ARRAY_AGG` in the same step with real data and complex subqueries seem to give me the exact position relation expected in a key-value pair! Was that a coincidence? Or using multiple `ARRAY_AGG` in the same step would allow me to retain that relationship for sure?

Considerations:

- Please ignore that doing that, if the array columns has `NULL` values, it will give an error;
- and if I decided to `IGNORE NULLS`, I would literally lose the array position relationship.

Comment: Everything having the same order (possibly even consistently) is still an arbitrary order, it just means that there isn't any guarantee and you shouldn't rely on it, because it might change between BigQuery releases, or the size of your dataset, or an arbitrary other factor.

Answer (score 1):

Admitting the answer is that there is not any guarantee that the same order will be retained (as Mark commented, and as written in BigQuery Documentation), if someone modeling this type of data decided to go with a Struct of Arrays, instead of the simpler-to-model Array of Structs, there is still a way to guarantee the order.

If you have a key for the values you're trying to aggregate, using `ORDER BY` as an argument of `ARRAY_AGG()` will do the trick. Just remember that if you are aggregating two table to model a Struct of Arrays, and the left one has joining keys with no match to the right one, the `IGNORE NULLS` conditions needs to be used!

Below, some code for BigQuery Standard SQL to help you test/play with that:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH entities AS (
    SELECT 1    AS entity_id
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
),
properties AS (
    SELECT 
        1       AS entity_id, 
        10      AS property_id,
        "a"     AS type, 
        TRUE    AS flag,
        "DONE"  AS status
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 11, "b", TRUE , "TO DO"
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 12, "c", FALSE, "DOING"
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 20, "a", TRUE , "TO DO"
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 21, "b", FALSE, "DONE"
)
SELECT 
    entity_id, 
    STRUCT(
        ARRAY_AGG(type   IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY property_id)  AS type, 
        ARRAY_AGG(flag   IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY property_id)  AS flag,
        ARRAY_AGG(status IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY property_id)  AS status
    )                                                           AS properties 
FROM entities 
LEFT JOIN properties USING(entity_id) 
GROUP BY entity_id
```

[Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss9QI.png)